# Gem::InstallError: minitest requires Ruby version ~> 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, minitest

Currently I am getting following error while doing bundle install

```
Gem::InstallError: minitest requires Ruby version ~> 2.2
```

It is trying to install latest minitest gem version (i.e. 5.12.2 which is released on September 29, 2019)

I checked my both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files but I didn't found my traces of minitest gem. So I am thinking it is a dependency gem.

I tried to do forcefully install its version to **4.7.5** which is previous version by defining in gem file as `gem 'minitest', '4.7.5'` But still it is trying to install version **5.12.2**.

System details:

- ruby 2.1.5p273
- bundler (1.12.5)
- Rails 3.2.17

So how can I fix this issue.

**EDIT**

After debugging I found that rspec-core has dependency of minitest.

Answer (score 8):

I just got this error when rebuilding the bundle of an old Rails program. I checked `Gemfile` and the gem wasn't there. I deleted `Gemfile.lock` and didn't get the error when I rebuilt the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 4.7.5'
```

Edit your Gemfile something like this. Make sure there are no minitest gems already installed, remove them if any.

```
gem list | grep minitest
```